# flutter firebase with streambuilder: Is server fee going to increase exponentially?

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, stream-builder

I'm beginner in flutter-fire app [: And here i've got a simple issue but not easy to figure out.

When we use Streambuilder in the app, we can usually see awesome synchronization between UI and DB on time. I'm really feeling joyful when using Streambuilder. It seemed like only beautiful things would happen with Streambuilder.

Meanwhile, a suspicious question popped out. When we enter print('hello world!'); in the Streambuilder, we can see that RUN console is printing out the phrase every milliseconds, otherwise would be just printed once. It means that RAM usage is extremely increased. When it comes to DB synchronization, we can easily guess that the use of Streambuilder leads to huge usage of client-server communication fee, which in my case is Firebase fee.

So, here is my question.
Can i feel free to use Streambuilder when the stream is connected to DB(in my case, firebase)?
I'm worrying about communication fee between UI and firebase, because streambuilder seems like literally using huge amount of energy every milliseconds(IMO additionally, server fee) unlike normal builders. Especially when the length of collection is so long that reading the collection once may cost a lot of energy, the fee would increase a lot more on and on, because the streambuilder have to check thousands of firebase documents only to figure out a single line of condition.

I guess many backend-connected flutter methods use the Streambuilder, so someone could clearly figure it out how much we're gonna pay for Google when we use Streambuilder. I know it's quite ambiguous question, but hope you understand. [:

Answer (score 1):

Content coming from the Firebase database, whether FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder, pays only for the query value that has been processed once, and after that, in case the same response value is the same for the same query, it does not pay for that cost and displays the stored list stored in the cache on the client screen again. .

And check that it's not being called on something like setState. if so, of course StreamBuilder is called again.